# Ubuntu 16.04 download to use Turtlebot3

Tags: downloads

I am extremely new to Linux and Ubuntu and programming as a whole.

As part of my research, I will be using the Turtlebot3 so I am working my way through the turtlebot E-Manual. I have already finished the ROS Programming booklet.
(link: http://emanual.robotis.com/docs/en/platform/turtlebot3/pc_setup/#install-ubuntu-on-remote)

I am looking to install Ubuntu 16.04 on my Windows OS and use Ubuntu through VMWare.

However, the download link that is provided to me has me confused as to how I can install Ubuntu 16.04. It does not seem to have anywhere to select a download.

Has anyone a correct link for this? I cannot use Torrent on my college PC.

Thanks,
James

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On the download link, there is an option for "See all Ubuntu mirrors" which will direct you to here: https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+cdmirrors

From there, choose a site, and there should be an option to download a 16.04 .iso.

For instance, here's one from Princeton: http://mirror.math.princeton.edu/pub/ubuntu-iso/16.04.6/